# Printer requiered for industrial printer

Tags: printer

Need industrial printer (print in paper bags papers) which can print with following spec,

- upto 42inch paper
- multicolor
- want to print upto 200GSM paper
- sheet feed and roll feed
- low quality print is enough
- lower ink consumption
- faster printing ability